# Pygame: circular motion with Bresenham's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, game-mechanics, python, pygame

I'm trying to figure out a way to move an object in a circular path. I read about Bresenham's circle algorithm, but all the codes available online draw an entire circle.

For my game, I want it so that when the ball enters a region, it'll begin to move in a circular path and when it leaves the region, it'll go back into moving in a straight path from its tangential velocity.

As of right now, I'm trying to figure out the algorithm to include in my game loop. I have the object updating its position every iteration. I use Bresenham's algorithm to decide whether to go right or go diagonal. I want it to draw the upper left portion of a circle

This is what I get:

[image: the result]

Here is my code at the moment:

```
# Drawing Curves with Midpt Circle Theorem
import pygame, sys, random, math
from pygame.locals import *

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))


        self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) 
        self.jom = pygame.Rect(100,100,2,2)

    def run(self):


        running = True

        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    running = False
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False


            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0,0,0), self.jom)



            ## Center of Curvature
            centercurv = (104,103)


            ## Update Position
                ## eqn of circle (x-104)**2 + (y-103)**2 - r**2 = 0, r == 5
            #circleeqn = (self.jom.x-centercurv[0])**2 + (self.jom.y-centercurv[1])**2
            #goright = (self.jom.x+1
            eR = -2*self.jom.x+2*centercurv[0]+1
            eD1 = -2*self.jom.x - 2*self.jom.y + 2*centercurv[0] + 2*centercurv[1] + 2
            print(eR,eD1)
            if abs(eR)-abs(eD1) > 0:
                #self.jom.x += 2
                self.jom.y -= 1
                print('1')
            elif abs(eR)-abs(eD1) < 0:
                #self.jom.x+=2
                print('2')
            else:
                if eR < 0 and eD1 < 0:
                    #self.jom.x+=2
                    print('3')
                elif eR > 0 and eD1 > 0:
                    self.jom.y -= 1
                    print('4')
            self.jom.x += 1

            pygame.display.flip()

        print('Quitting')
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
game = Game()
game.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

Bresenham's algorithm is specifically built to draw circles with fixed-point mathematics; that is, to *rasterize* circles.  For what you're doing you're almost certainly better off with a much more abstract representation of your circular motion — that is, you want to keep track of your character's *angular velocity* and to simply move it with constant angular velocity about the center point of the circle.  This decouples the *representation* of your ball's physical state (position and velocity) from the *display* of that state, which is a Very Good Idea.  Abstractly, this would look something like:

```
while (not in containing region) {
  ball.Position += deltaTime*ball.Velocity;
}
if ( entering containing region ) {
  Vector RelativePosition = ball.Position - region.CircleCenter;
  float AngularVelocity = length(ball.Velocity)/length(RelativePosition);
}
while ( in containing region ) {
  float s = sin(AngularVelocity*deltaTime);
  float c = cos(AngularVelocity*deltaTime);
  Vector newRelativePos;
  newRelativePos.x = c*ball.RelativePosition.x - s*ball.RelativePosition.y;
  newRelativePos.y = s*ball.RelativePosition.x + c*ball.RelativePosition.y;
  RelativePosition = newRelativePos;
  ball.Position = region.CircleCenter + RelativePosition;
}
if ( leaving containing region ) {
  Vector normalizedPosition = RelativePosition.normalize();
  // linear velocity is orthogonal to normalized position
  ball.Velocity.x = -AngularVelocity*normalizedPosition.y;
  ball.Velocity.y = AngularVelocity*normalizedPosition.x;
}
```

This essentially says 'while the ball is in free motion, just update by the usual P<sub>new</sub> = P<sub>old</sub>+V*dt rule, but when the ball is contained, update the position using constant angular velocity by saying θ<sub>new</sub> = θ<sub>old</sub>+ω*dt and then P = P<sub>center</sub>+(RelativeP rotated by θ), where RelativeP is P<sub>entry</sub>-P<sub>center</sub> — the relative position on entry to the volume.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have not thought about angular velocity. I have a stupid question though, how did you find the newRelativePos? I couldn't exactly understand why c*ball.RelativePosition.x - s*ball.RelativePosition.y returns the new relative x value.

Comment: Also, how do you account for the new position not being integer values? Do you round up or round down

Comment: @rcs Not a stupid question at all!  It's a very complicated matter.  Essentially, I'm treating the RelativePosition as a vector from the region's CircleCenter to the position of the ball; this vector gets initialized as the region is entered, and then updated every tick while the ball is in the region.  The 'update' is the two lines setting the x and y positions (and note that we update both x _and_ y based off of the old values, then assign both over back to RelativePosition at once); those two lines are equivalent to multiplying by the 2d _rotation matrix_ for rotation by &omega;*dt.

Comment: (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix for more details on rotation matrices).  And I would store the position as float not just while it's in the region but all the time - it'll lead to cleaner updates.  Generally I would just round-to-nearest, but how you convert from floating-point position to integer screen-space position is almost entirely up to you, and there are advantages to the different methods.